# Computer beeps 5 times and restarts constantly before BIOS

Tags: cpu, motherboard, beep-code

A few days ago, the computer I built about 4 years ago suddenly stopped booting up. When I turn it on, it restarts constantly without ever reaching BIOS. The fans turn on for about 10 seconds and then it shuts off for about 5 seconds and repeats.

It is built with:

- Gigabyte GA-H110M-52H-GSM motherboard
- Intel i5 6500 CPU
- EVGA 600W power supply
- 16GB (8GB x2) Crucial DDR4 RAM
- PNY GeForce GT710 GPU
- IntelAX200NGW WiFi/Bluetooth card

So far I have tried:

- Got a speaker to check beep codes. 5 long beeps on start up, per Gigabytes web site, this appears to mean a CPU issue
- Changed the CMOS battery
- Removed and re-seated everything in the computer
- Re-seated the CPU and reapplied thermal paste
- Unplugged everything except the CPU, RAM, and a monitor
- Tried one RAM stick at a time in each slot
- Tested the power supply with a multimeter. Didn't notice anything out of the ordinary.

After all of this, I am still having the same issue. It just happened so suddenly that I can't think of what might have caused it. Shortly before it started I was having some issues with my WiFi cards staying connected to the network after a Windows update the day before. Not sure if that has any correlation.

Anyone have any suggestions on how to continue troubleshooting? I don't have another power supply, motherboard, or CPU to test out, so is there any way to test the functionality without testing a second one? I appreciate any help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It looks that this question seems related to "GA-H110M-52H-GSM 5 beeps" on Google tells that it might be an issue with the RAM.

So my suggestion as an technical supporter would be:

- Reduce the system connection to the minimum.
- Meaning; remove any RAM except one and try to start beep
  continue?

If yes, move the same RAM to the next slot. Continue until all done. Repeat this with the rest of your RAM sticks.

- Beep continues the same? If yes; remove any extension cards
  repeat with one RAM.
- Beep continues the same? If yes; remove the RAM entirely check if the beep changes.

If not, we need to know what kind of BIOS is been used.